# Raise Error Concatenation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Step 1 :I created a custom error message in sys.messages

```
EXEC sp_addmessage   
    @msgnum = 50001,   
    @severity = 10,  
    @msgtext =   
        N'Error 50001, severity 10, state 1 was raised, Please check mdf file.' ,  
    @lang = 'us_english',
    @replace='REPLACE';
```

Step 2: Inside a Job when a condition is met I am raising the error

```
RAISERROR(50001, 10,1,@freespacePct, @dbname,@drive) with LOG;
```

I would like to see FreespacePCt,database name and drive details inside the error message.

But when I look at the raised error I am just seeing just what I declared inside the `sp_addmessage`. How can I log the other details?

Message I am seeing :

> Error 50001, severity 10, state 1 was raised, Please check mdf file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add some parameters to your @msgtext so SQL Server knows where you put your data. Something like so:

```
EXEC sp_addmessage   
    @msgnum = 50001,   
    @severity = 10,  
    @msgtext =   
        N'Error 50001, severity 10, state 1 was raised, Please check mdf file. The freespace is %d percent for %s residing on %s' ,  
    @lang = 'us_english',
    @replace='REPLACE';
```

Then, you would raise it....

```
declare @freespacePct int = 45
        ,@dbname sysname = 'MYDB'
        ,@drive varchar(16) = 'F:/'
RAISERROR(50001, 10,1,@freespacePct, @dbname,@drive) with LOG;
```

That would return:

> Error 50001, severity 10, state 1 was raised, Please check mdf file.
>   The freespace is 45 percent for MYDB residing on F:/

The `%s` is used for strings, `%d` is used for signed integers. You can find all of the type specifications in the `RAISERROR` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
Type specification  Represents
d or i              Signed integer
o                   Unsigned octal
s                   String
u                   Unsigned integer
x or X              Unsigned hexadecimal
```

> These type specifications are based on the ones originally defined for
>   the [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) function in the C standard library. The type
>   specifications used in RAISERROR message strings map to Transact-SQL
>   data types, while the specifications used in printf map to C language
>   data types. Type specifications used in printf are not supported by
>   RAISERROR when Transact-SQL does not have a data type similar to the
>   associated C data type. For example, the %p specification for pointers
>   is not supported in RAISERROR because Transact-SQL does not have a
>   pointer data type.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. This is what I am trying to achieve.